# Cómo ejecutar una función después de ejecutar jobs encadenados - laravel

Tags: laravel, jobs

Tengo esta cadena de jobs en *Laravel*:

```
public function sendTest($id)
    {
    $meo = $this->meoRepository->getMeo($id);

    Bus::chain([

        new GprInsight($meo),

        new MeoDataGenerator($meo),

        new MailDigestReport($this->mailTaskRepository->getPendingMailTaskByMeoId($id), false),

    ])->onQueue('gmb')->dispatch();

}
```

Esto funciona después del segundo intento porque primero ejecuta todas las líneas de código antes de iniciar los jobs (*así me lo demuestra el debug, termina siendo nulo después del primer intento y funciona en el 2do después de haberse creado anteriormente*), como resultado mi último job falla en el primer intento, ya que el objeto que quiero enviarle está vacío momentáneamente y solo se crea después de haber ejecutado los dos jobs anteriores, quiero que el último job se ejecute después de que termine el segundo, ya que se tarda unos 4 minutos en hacerlo.

Intenté con una función después del segundo job como este:

```
public function sendTest($id)
{
    $meo = $this->meoRepository->getMeo($id);
    Bus::chain([
        new GprInsight($meo),
        new MeoDataGenerator($meo),
        function ($id){
            new MailDigestReport($this->mailTaskRepository->getPendingMailTaskByMeoId($id), false);
        }
    ])->onQueue('gmb')->dispatch();
}
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> [2020-11-10 06:48:42] local.ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency
> [Parameter #0 [  $id ]] in class
> App\Services\DigestReportService {"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException(code:
> 0): Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $id ]] in
> class App\Services\DigestReportService at
> D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:180)
> [stacktrace]

¿Cómo podría lograr mi objetivo?

muchas gracias!

Comment: Por qué no usas dispatchSync() ?

Comment: @L.Flor obtengo el error
Error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingChain::dispatchSync()

Comment: además, leyendo de dispatchSync dice que lo que eso hace es ejecutar inmediatamente el siguiente trabajo, lo que busco es que se tome su tiempo, el 3er trabajo necesita una variable creada en el 2do

Comment: Qué versión de Laravel estás usando?

Comment: @L.Flor laravel 8, logré solucionarlo de una manera distinta, voy a publicarlo

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que esto sí lo hacía en una fila o cola, pero resulta que primero instancia todas las variables antes de empezar a trabajar, por ende **me devolvía nulas las variables que requería** debido a que recién se generaban después de ejecutar los jobs, cosa que no quería

solución, meter la ejecución de un job dentro del otro, prácticamente hacerlo manualmente, me despedí del bus::chain

```
public function sendTest($id)
{
    $meo = $this->meoRepository->getMeo($id);
    GprInsight::dispatch($meo, true)->onQueue('gmb');
}
```

esto lo que hace es enviar al primer job, lo que debe hacer, luego en el 2do job hacer lo mismo para llamar al 3ro

```
            if($this->chain){
               MeoDataGenerator::dispatch($this->meo, $this->chain)->onQueue('gmb');
            }
```

y por último ya solo llamamos al último job

```
    if ($this->chain){
        MailDigestReport::dispatch($mailTask, $this->meo, true, $this->chain)->onQueue('gmb');
    }
```

nota: los > true son valores de chain, ya que en los constructores de cada job se los estoy poniendo para trabajar con los if, ejemplo

```
public function __construct(Meo $meo, bool $chain = false)
{
    $this->meo = $meo;
    $this->meoRepository = new MeoRepository();
    $this->chain = $chain;
}
```